# Log errors to database with Django on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, logging, error-handling

Is there a project that can log errors in requests to Django on [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) to the datastore (like [django-db-log](http://code.google.com/p/django-db-log/) or [django.crashlog](http://code.google.com/p/django-crashlog/))?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in [`google.appengine.ext.ereporter`](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/ereporter.py) module:

> A logging handler that records
>   information about unique exceptions.
>
> 'Unique' in this case is defined as a
>   given (exception class, location)
>   tuple. Unique exceptions are logged to
>   the datastore with an example
>   stacktrace and an approximate count of
>   occurrences, grouped by day and
>   application version.
>
> A cron handler, in
>   google.appengine.ext.ereporter.report_generator,
>   constructs and emails a report based
>   on the previous day's exceptions.

See also: [Using the ereporter module for easy error reporting](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Using-the-ereporter-module-for-easy-error-reporting-in-App-Engine).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out [Native Django on GAE](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/01/Native-Django-on-App-Engine). It's a non-relational port of Django to Google's App Engine.
2. Another project,
   [google-app-engine-django](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/), looks
   like an intermediate "helper" to get
   you going, without the full port.

Comment: @Wraith - Thanks for the suggestion. I'd rather avoid mediators just for this logging mechanism - it adds an awful lot of complexity and room for errors for one very specific use. But I appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a project [Django-GAE-log](http://bitbucket.org/brianmhunt/django-gae-log/) to solve this issue. Thoughts and input are welcome!

Comment: You may want to take a look at the approach my ereporter module takes (see other answer): By registering a Python logging handler, you can capture all calls to logging.exception and process them as you wish.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Great tip! Interestingly enough I was just perusing your blog for something on cursors+pagination. :) Thanks!